# How to work with a remote repository containing many branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-push, git-pull

Let us assume that a remote (central) repository has several branches and in the beginning I have locally the exact copy of the remote repository.

Now I want to change something in one of the branches on the remote repository. I could do some changes to the local copy of the remote branch and then try to push it but I guess that in this case I can have a merge-conflict that will be hard to resolve. So, I guess that one need to do the following:

1. Create a local copy (branch `C`) of the local copy (branch `B`) of the remote branch (branch `A`).
2. Do changes to this "copy of the copy" (branch `C`).
3. Pull the remote branch again (branch `A`). It will update the local copy of the remote repository (branch `B`).
4. Merge locally the "copy of the copy" (branch `C`, containing your changes) into the the (updated) local copy (branch `B`) of the remote repository (branch `A`, containing changes done by others).
5. Now you can push the local copy of the remote repository (branch `B`) (containing your changes and changes of others) to the remote branch (`A`).

I guess that my description might be confusing. So, I try to summarize it with different words: Copy `A` into `B`, copy `B` into `C`, modify `C`, update `B` using the new state of `A` (basically copy `A` into `B` again), merge `C` into `B`, push `B` into `A`.

Is it the way to go?

Comment: This sounds painfully complicated to me.  If you want to change a remote branch, what is preventing you from just pulling, modifying it, and then pushing again?  Do you think your suggested workflow would really avoid merge conflicts, and are merge conflicts such a problem for you?

Comment: The motivation behind my workflow is that in case of a merge conflict I will have the two conflicting branches locally and I will need to merge them locally. So, it is not about avoiding a merge conflict it is about expecting it and being better prepared to it. Maybe the problem is that I do not know how to resolve a conflict between a local and a remote branches.

Comment: In Git, when you merge it is _always_ between two local branches.  Unless you are talking about doing a merge on the remote via something like a pull request on GitHub or Bitbucket.  But even then, you don't have to merge there, you can always do any merge you want locally.

Comment: You say that the merge is always local but then I do not understand what should I merge into what. I have a remote branch `A` and its local version `B`. Now I want to push the local branch `B` into the remote branch `A` but it will not always work (we might have a conflict). So, what should I merge with what locally?

Comment: Hi Roman, can you tell me clearly what you are trying to here, and then I can suggest a workflow?  Which branch is getting merged into which branch?

Comment: I have create a local copy of a remote branch by "pull". Now I want to modify the local branch and push these modification back to the remote branch. I assume that at the moment of push the remote branch will be modified by someone else and I will have a conflict and I am not prepared to that. I do not know how should I resolve it if it happens.

Comment: Got it now.  Let me post something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very common workflow in Git for working with a shared branch (i.e. a branch which several engineers may be modifying at the same/almost the same time) is the following:

```
git pull origin the_branch
# work work work
git push origin the_branch
```

As you correctly pointed out, you might hit a problem when you go to push, because at the moment you push, other folks may themselves have already pushed other commits on top of `the_branch`.  There are two basic approaches at your fingertips here.  First, you could pull merge the remote `the_branch` into your local branch, and then push out:

```
git pull origin the_branch
# possibly resolve merge conflicts, then make a merge commit
git push origin the_branch
```

This approach would create a merge commit in your local branch, and that commit might typically therefore appear as part of the history of the remote branch as well.  If you don't like merge commits, then rebasing is another option here:

```
git pull --rebase origin the_branch
# again, possibly resolve merge conflicts
git push origin the_branch
```

If you go the rebase option, then you would be laying your commits down directly on the top of the remote branch, as if your local branch already had the commits recently made by other people.

There is a lingering edge case with either approach.  What happens if new material comes in between the time your merge/rebase and the time you go to push.  If that were to happen, then you'd have to merge/rebase again.  But in my experience, this almost never happens, and actually I can't even remember this happening to me once.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is standard development practice - the local and remote branches are usually on the same commit (a and b in your case), with development done on a third branch C.

Before pushing to the remote you pull, and then rebase (this is generally preferred to a merge) C on top of the result and push back.

This is the safest option IMO, and good practice.